# IBM MQ Message Throttling

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

We are using IBM MQ and we are facing some serious problems regarding controlling its asynchronous delivery to its recipient.We are having some java listeners configured, now the problem is that we need to control the messages coming towards listener, because the messages coming to server are in millions count and server machine dont have that much capacity t process so many threads at a time, so is there any way like throttling on IBM MQ side where we can configure preetch limit like Apache MQ does?

or is there any other way to achieve this?

Currently we are closing connection with IBM MQ when some X limit has reached on listener, but doesen't seems to be efficient way.

Please guys help us out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Generally with message queueing technologies like MQ the point of the queue is that the sender is decoupled from the receiver. If you're having trouble with message volumes then the answer is to let them queue up on the receiver queue and process them as best you can, not to throttle the sender.

The obvious answer is to limit the maximum number of threads that your listeners are allowed to take up. I'm assuming you're using some sort of MQ threadpool? What platform are you using that provides unlimited listener threads?

From your description, it almost sounds like you have some process running that - as soon as it detects a message in the queue - it reads the message, starts up a new thread and goes back and looks at the queue again. This is the WRONG approach.

You should have a defined number of process threads running (start with one and scale up as required, and within limits of your server) which read from the queue themselves. They would each open the queue in shared mode and either get-with-wait or do immediate get with a sleep if you get a MQRC 2033 (no messages in queue).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in the application server environment, then the maxPoolDepth property on the activationSpec will define the maximum ServerSessionPool size for the MDB - decreasing this will throttle the number messages being delivered concurrently.

Of course, if your MDB (or javax.jms.MessageListener in the JSE environment) does nothing but hand the message to something else (or, worse, just spawn an unmanaged Thread and start it) onMessage will spin rapidly and you can still encounter problems. So in that case you need to limit other resources too, e.g. via threadpool configuration.

Closing the connection to the QM is never an efficient way, as the MQCONN/MQDISC cycle is expensive.